# C# ActiveX VLC plugin - audio issue

Tags: c#, vlc

My app (C#) allows the user to choose # of VLC players to view simultaneously through the use of the AxVLCPlugin2 plugin.  I am able to successfully load the VLC players and play streams. However, I've run into a pretty serious issue with audio control.

Whenever I mute/unmute or change volume on one player, it applies it to all other vlc players also.  Anyone know what the issue is and how to resolve?

Sample code:

```
//create VLC players
for(int i = 1; i <= total_boxes; i++)
{
   AxAXVLC.AxVLCPlugin2 vlc_player = new AxAXVLC.AxVLCPlugin2();
   vlc_player.Name = plyr + i.ToString();                
   this.Controls.Add(vlc_player);               
}

private void Mute_Player()
{
//Set control to desired vlc player   
AxAXVLC.AxVLCPlugin2 vlc_plyr = this.Controls.Find(clicked_vlc_box_name, true).FirstOrDefault() as AxAXVLC.AxVLCPlugin2;

   vlc_plyr.audio.toggleMute();  <---- PROBLEM: This or vlc_plyr.audio.volume changes volume on all players instead of the selected player ONLY

   return;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there are more than one players? Or is it a single engine playing multiple files?

Comment: Definitely more than one player since I'm able to view the live stream videos being played.  Just can't control the volume individually.

Comment: Also, I can see the specific player control name (w/breakpoint) at the first line of code in the MutePlayer() function.  Hence, if I am trying to change volume for player 4 lets say, I see vlc_player.Name = "player4".  So I know the program is pointing to the correct player, but for whatever reason it changes the volume on all simultaneously.    Lastly, as you can see in my snippet above, I'm not using the libvlc engine, rather the ActiveX VLC plugin to create the video players.

Comment: please don't use the active X plugin, it is NOT maintained for a long time. libvlcsharp is the recommended way to go if you use .NET.